# Live data on a web based GIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, cesium

I'm looking to implement a 3D/2D tactical display in a browser. This should be capable of plotting maybe 100 tracks and their histories with 0.5 second updates.

I've researched the available technologies and considering using the following stack.

- GeoServer with PostGIS backend
- CesiumJS with ol3-cesium
- OpenLayers 3 - supports WFS

Most of these technologies seem to be based around serving static data rather than live dynamic data. I'd ideally like a high performance solution using WebSockets rather than HTTP polling, however I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Can anyone provide any recommendations/experiences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those technologies are going to be fine to setup your base imagery and terrain, but your dynamic data will best served via CZML.  You can setup CZML streaming to allow your data to be continually updated and it will allow you to group your objects for a much easier filtering of visible objects.

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/CZML-Guide